# Laravel validator require

Tags: laravel-5, model-validation

Ao colocar a opção `required` nas regras de validação do `Laravel`

```
$validator=\Validator::make($request->all(),['po_bairro'=>'require|string|min:5|max:50']);
```

ele exige que tenha o valor para poder continuar o programa.

Contudo, no meu caso, eu não coloquei 'require' como opção. Eu setei apenas `string|min:5|max:50` nas regras.

```
$validator=\Validator::make($request->all(),['po_bairro'=>'string|min:5|max:50']);
```

Ao enviar o formulário com o ***campo vazio*** (`po_bairro`), ele me dá o **erro** da regra `min`.

Aí vem a pergunta, mas eu não setei require, o validador não deveria deixar passar?

Comment: Dê um dump no `$request->input('po_bairro')` para ver como chega. Quando envia ele vazio. Estou considerando e tentando entender que o "" esteja entrando como string, entao ele cai na regra.

Comment: Teste um `array_filter($request->all())`. Assim o validator realmente nao recebera nada desse campo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aí vem a pergunta, mas eu não setei require, o validador não deveria deixar passar?

A resposta é não porque, na própria documentação existe um trecho que responde a sua dúvida:

***string***

*The field under validation must be a string. If you would like to allow the field to also be `null`, you should assign the `nullable` rule to the field.*

**tradução**

O campo em validação deve ser uma `string`. Se você quiser permitir que o campo também seja `nulo`, você deve atribuir a regra `nullable` ao campo.

---

Mediante esse explicação mude o seu código de validação para:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), ['po_bairro' => 'nullable|min:5|max:50']);
```

***Referencias:***

- [nullable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-nullable)
- [string](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-string)

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!!